# Building the signing and release prepartion of android apps into jenkins/hudson?

Tags: android, hudson, jenkins, android-install-apk

I've got a handful of side-project apps on the go at home, I've setup a Jenkins installation to check them out and build APKs, which I then transfer over to my handset and play around with.

I'm looking to release some of these freely on the market, so I need to sign them with a certificate and prepare the final APK.

Is it possible to do this from Jenkins? For example, could I have one build target that generates my "in development" APKs, and also have that target (or another) create the final APK files ready to go?

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the signing is possible to do automatically (by command line or similar), then the answer is "Yes".

There are several ways to achieve this, but firstly: *Is there any good reason not to sign every build?*

Signing every build would mean that you don't need any extra configuration to create a releasable artifact, and you know that what you test and what you deploy are the same things.

If you want to be selective about what builds you sign, two approaches come to mind:

- [Parameterized builds](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build): These are environment variables that can be customized when you click Build now. You can add a flag that you later react on in a build step.
- Add another job that picks up the artifacts from your main build job and signs them, using `https://jenkins-server/job/jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/` or one of the approaches here: [How to access Hudson job1 artifacts from another job2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337316/how-to-access-hudson-job1-artifacts-from-another-job2/5337800#5337800)

Answer (score 5):

In the standard Android ant build file is a release target contained. This will if started without further configuration just build an unsigned apk. As Christopher pointed out to do a signed build you can use `key.store`, `key.store.password` and `key.alias`,`key.alias.password` to configure your keystore and generate signed apks through the ant script. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html#ReleaseMode) on this may fprovide further information on configuring the build.

Comment: It is possible: just add "key.store.password" and "key.alias.password" to your properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... the easiest way imho is to automate it with Maven Android Plugin. The samples project has the MorseFlash example I wrote in there that has the whole release process automated including jarsigning, zipaligning and proguard runs, switching between development and production config and more.

This can all be done on the command line and therefore on Hudson. Btw if you are interested I did presentations about Maven and Android as well as testing and CI for Android at AnDevCon and the slides are on my web site. http://www.simpligility.com